# Maxima: taylor: assumed to be zero:

Tags: maxima

I am trying to calculate the series expansion of the Kretschmann scalar of some metric with maxima: my code is as follows:

```
kill(all);
load("ctensor");

dim: 4;
ct_coords: [t,r,theta,phi];

depends(m,r);
depends(A,[r,theta]);
depends(B,[r,theta]);
depends(C,[r,theta]);
depends(G,[r,theta]);
depends(H,[r,theta]);

lg: matrix([-(1-2*m(r)/r+a^2*A(r,theta)),0,0,-a*G(r,theta)],[0,1/(1-2*m(r)/r)+a^2*B(r,theta),0,0],[0,0,r^2+a^2*C(r,theta),0],[-a*G(r,theta),0,0,r^2*sin(theta)^2+a^2*H(r,theta)]);

cmetric(false);
christof(false);
/*ricci(false);
uricci(false);
einstein(false);
leinstein(false);*/
riemann(false);
lriemann(false);
uriemann(false);
rinvariant();

taylor(kinvariant,a,0,2);
```

It seems that the macro works, but it produces weird results in the Taylor series: it continually outputs lines as follows:

```
                                                                    18
taylor: assumed to be zero: (                                      a  )
                                                                    18
taylor: assumed to be zero: (                                      a  )
                                                                    18
taylor: assumed to be zero: (                                      a  )
                                                                    18
taylor: assumed to be zero: (                                      a  )
```

and never produces the desired Taylor series: is this a bug? How do I fix my code?

If needed my version is 5.43.2

**EDIT** I have upgrade to the latest version (5.44) but still get the same output

Comment: I suspect the messages mean that `taylor` is attempting to simplify the expression by making assumptions. I see that `kinvariant` is a large expression, and I find that `diff(kinvariant, a)` is already very large, so I suspect `diff(kinvariant, a, 2)` will be larger still. However, `diff(kinvariant, a)` evaluated at a = 0 yields 0. (Is that to be expected? I guess it should be verified.) My advice at this point is to post a message to the Maxima mailing list, where the maintainer fo the ctensor package, Viktor Toth, will see it. See: https://sourceforge.net/projects/maxima/lists/maxima-discuss

Comment: @RobertDodier Thanks for the comment: I have posted a question as suggested. Also:in fact it is expected that `diff(kinvariant,a)` is zero when `a=0`, this is why I am expanding to the second order